# Why can I not compare ObjectIDs across contexts in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is my test case

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[TestPerson entityName]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = \"mark\""];

NSArray *results = [_controller.mainContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
TestPerson *mark1 = results.firstObject;
XCTAssertNil(error);
XCTAssertEqual(1, results.count);
XCTAssertTrue([@"mark" isEqualToString:mark1.firstName]);

results = [[_controller backgroundContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
TestPerson *mark2 = results.firstObject;
XCTAssertNil(error);
XCTAssertEqual(1, results.count);
XCTAssertTrue([@"mark" isEqualToString:mark2.firstName]);

XCTAssertTrue([mark1.objectID isEqual:mark2.objectID]);
```

My stack looks like this

```
PSC--+--privateContexts--mainContext
     |
     +------------backgroundContexts
```

Both firstNames evaluate to mark. The setUp and tearDown code is simple. setUp:

```
NSError *error = nil;

_controller = [CoreDataController new];
_controller.model = [CoreDataTests model];
_controller.storeType = NSInMemoryStoreType;
_controller.storeConfiguration = nil;
_controller.storeURL = nil;
_controller.storeOptions = nil;
[_controller createCoreDataStack];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = _controller.mainContext;
TestPerson *mark = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[TestPerson entityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];
mark.firstName = @"mark";
mark.lastName = @"camper";
[context save:&error];

TestPerson *mary = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[TestPerson entityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];
mary.firstName = @"mary";
mary.lastName = @"camper";
[context save:&error];
XCTAssert(error == nil);
```

tearDown:

```
_controller = nil;
```

description of mark1:

```
<TestPerson: 0x7fd212f48c10> (entity: TestPerson; id: 0x7fd212f46700 <x-coredata:///TestPerson/t9DB3981E-74CE-42CE-B054-9E5C280BEDC72> ; data: {
firstName = mark;
lastName = camper;
})
```

mark2:

```
<TestPerson: 0x7fd212f1d930> (entity: TestPerson; id: 0x7fd212f3dc40 <x-coredata://D9092214-6EC3-4918-9360-4663ABC56E37/TestPerson/p1> ; data: {
firstName = mark;
lastName = camper;
})
```

The assertion failure is `XCTAssertTrue([mark1.objectID isEqual:mark2.objectID]);`

Is there some subtly I am missing?

Comment: How and where are you creating the contexts?

Comment: They are apart of my tested class. Background contexts are created as `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` with psc set and returned from the method call `_controller.backgroundContext`. I'll change the syntax since it's not clear. The main context is a readonly as `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and its private queue as a parent. The private queue is `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` with psc set. Both private and background use the same psc.

Comment: The contexts share a PSC, but the main and private contexts aren't tied together, so you'll get different objects that just happen to have the same entity contents.

Comment: I thought I had a solution turns out it was just a programming mistake. Why do they have to be related? I thought the PSC was responsible for managing its contexts. If you have any documentation on this, post a solution and I'll accept it.

Comment: I changed it as you suggested and it works.